# Have problems in the touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitouch

I have a UIView with a UIScrollView and I want to catch the event touches but I can not.
Not goes into any method below. What is the problem?

```
- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) toca withEvent: (UIEvent *) evento
{
     NSLog (@ "touchesEnded");

}
- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) toca withEvent: (UIEvent *) evento
{

     NSLog (@ "touchesBegan");

}
- (Void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *) toca withEvent: (UIEvent *) evento
{
     NSLog (@ "touchesMoved");
}
```

### Heading ##[image]

thank you

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a `UIView` with a `UIScrollView` added as a subview and you are trying to get touches on the `UIView`? Not the scrollview, correct?

Comment: I need to get the touches in UIViews or UIScrollView.
There is trouble attempting to capture the touches in UIScrollView? How do I let pass the touches to UIView?

Comment: implement these methods in your UIView.m

Comment: Pls chk whether i understood correct.. you have UIViews in UIScrollView and u need to capture the UIViews touch event right?

Comment: Added a printscreen of xib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use UIGestureRecognizer.
You can add it directly in your viewController:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap =
              [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:myView action:@selector(yourSelector:)];
          [myView addGestureRecognizer:tapp];
```

Otherwise you can add it directly with the interface boulder:
[image: add gesture recognizer]

after adding the gesture recognizer you can use it like a normal outlet.

Answer (score 1):

As Benny Dalby told there is a way of making subclass of UIScrollView and can perform your touch event

In your scroll view subclass implementation file you can perform these function

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];


}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];


}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];


}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Must be missing something because can not seem with these methods.
I googled some tutorials with the methods
- (Void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
- (Void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
- (Void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
- (Void) touchesCancelled: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
and implemented but without success.

Comment: I've had projects where the methods used and managed properly implement, this time I'm not getting. Any failure on my part that I am not a repair

I used the shape of Max_Power89 and works, do not know if it is the correct way to be doing.

Comment: Vishnu can you give me your email ?

Comment: @PedroMeira since this is public site i can't share my personal id. You can message ur mail id in this FB acc https://www.facebook.com/ImadeInfotech

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView is immune to touchesEnded, touchesBegan, touchesMoved etc.That is it prevents these methods from getting called in the ViewControler.

**Possibility 1 :**

Use UIGestureRecognizerDelegates to implement touch in ScrollView

**Possibility 2 :**

Create a subclass of UIScrollView class and override the touchesBegan: and other touch methods

Hope it Helps!!!